# Embedding XML (and other languages?) in Scala

Tags: scala, dsl

I'm wondering how the `scala.xml` library is implemented, to get an `Elem`-instance out of XML.

So I can write:

```
val xml = {
  <myxml>
    Some wired text withoud "'s or code like
    import x
    x.func()
    It's like a normal sting in triple-quotes.
  </myxml>
}

xml.text

String = 
 "
    Some text wired withoud "'s or code like
    import x
    x.func()
    It's like a normal sting in triple-quotes.
  "
```

A look at the source code doesn't gave me the insight, how this is achieved.
Is the "XML-detection" a (hard) scala language feature or is it an internal DSL? Because I would like to build my own things like this:

```
var x = LatexCode {
  \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}
}

x.toString

"\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}"
```

or

```
var y = PythonCode {
  >>> import something
  >>> something.func()
}

y.toString
"""import something ..."""

y.execute  // e.g. passed to python as python-script
```

or

```
object o extends PythonCode {
  import x
  x.y()
}

o.toString

"""import x...."""
```

I would like to avoid using such things like `PythonCode { """import ...""" }` as "DSL". And in scala, XML is magically transported to a `scala.xml`-Class; same with `Symbol` which I can get with `val a = 'symoblname`, but in the source code there's no clue how this is implemented.

How can I do something like that on myself, preferably as internal DSL?

Comment: Michael Fogus wrote a BASIC dsl in Scala which might be relevant to your question: https://github.com/fogus/baysick

Comment: I know that project, he uses `Symbol` and with this you can only represent one literal. `val x = 'import x` wouldn't work!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XML is a scala language feature (*) - see the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), section **1.5**.

I think that [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/string-interpolation.html) is coming in 2.10, however, which would at least allow you to define your own DSL:

```
val someLatex = latex"""\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}}"""
```

It's an experimental feature explained more fully in the SIP but has been additionally [blogged about by the prolific Daniel Sobral](http://dcsobral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/string-interpolation-on-scala-210.html). The point of this is (of course) that the correctness of the *code* in the String can be checked at compile time (well, to the extent possible in an untyped language :-) and your IDE can even help you write it (well, to the extent possible in an untyped language :-( )

(*) - *We might expect this to change in the future given the many shortcomings of the implementation. My understanding is that a combination of string interpolation and anti-xml may yet be the one true way*.

Comment: Err, why the downvote? Perhaps I have misunderstood the question?

Comment: Mind you, Scales is a pretty good library as well. I don't know why people are so fixated on anti-xml, and I think it's time to start spreading the word that there are other alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

It's an XML literal, just like `"foo"` is a string literal, `42` is an integer literal, `12.34` is a floating point literal, `'foo` is a symbol literal, `(foo) => foo + 1` is a function literal and so on.

Scala has fewer literals than other languages (for example, it doesn't have array literals or regexp literals), but it *does* have XML literals.

Note that in Scala 2.10 string literals become *vastly* more powerful by allowing you to intercept and re-interpret them using `StringContext`s. These more powerful string literals would allow you to implement all of your snippets, *including* XML without separate language support. It is likely that XML literals will be removed in a future version of the language.

Comment: With `StringContext` I'll be able to build my own "literals"? So that I doesn't need to use tripple-quotes anymore? Or is then the scala.xml-future like this: `"""<x>Text</x>""".text` instead of `<x>Text</x>.text`?